# What distance metric to use for traversal in a custom network as described?

Tags: java, machine-learning, networking, graph, distance

So I have a network of paths as shown below:

```
        A   B   C   D
        |   |   |   |           
    ========================    
        |   |   |   |           
        E   F   G   H


        I   J   K   L           
        |   |   |   |           
    ========================        
        |   |   |   |           
        M   N   o   P
```

What would be a good distance metric for calculating distances between two points (A-M, E-I, J-P, D-H) as marked by the dashed line?
Also what would be a good way to store this network in the database, currently storing the centers of the nodes and the endpoints of the roads depicted with `===` and calculating the points of contact based on the line equation.

```
--------|
|       A   B   C   D-----------|
|       |   |   |   |           |
|   ========================    |
|       |   |   |   |           |
|       E   F   G   H-----------|
|
|       |
|       |
|       |   |-------------------|
|       |                       |
|                               |
|       I   J   K   L           |
|       |   |   |   |           |
|   ========================    |   
|       |   |   |   |           |
|       M   N   o   P           |
|-------|           |-----------|
```